# How to figure the question into 100 in relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have two models **1. Subject 2. Question** and it has **One to many relation**. And a student can choose many subjects he want. And now I want to take a test through the subjects. And the test should be 100 marks test.**Now i need a way how to accomplish the 100 marks test. Suppose a student choose 3 subjects and if we divide 3 form 100 then it will be 33 (floor) or 34 (ceil) per subject but i want to round it to 100, how i accomplish this.** Here is my code for getting the questionsn

```
foreach ($student->departments as $key => $department){
                $majorSubjects[] =$department->subject_id;
            }

        $no_of_questions =100;
            $uniqueSubjects=array_unique($majorSubjects);
            $div = ceil($no_of_questions/count($uniqueSubjects));
            $mul = $div*count($uniqueSubjects);

            $subjects=Subject::whereIn('id',$majorSubjects)->get();
            }
```

and in my blade

```
 @foreach($subjects as $key => $subject)
              <li class=" {{$key == 0 ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="#tab_{{ $subject->id }}" data-toggle="tab">{{$subject->name}}</a></li>  
              @endforeach
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
              @if(!empty($subjects))
               @foreach($subjects as $key => $subject)
              <div class="tab-pane {{$key == 0 ? 'active' : ''}}" id="tab_{{ $subject->id }}">

                @foreach($subject->questions->random($div) as $num => $question)
                <form></form>
                @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `modulus` to get the remaining mark test.

```
$additional_mark_test = $no_of_questions % count($uniqueSubjects);
```

Put it in here.

```
foreach ($student->departments as $key => $department){
                $majorSubjects[] =$department->subject_id;
            }

        $no_of_questions =100;
            $uniqueSubjects=array_unique($majorSubjects);
            $div = ceil($no_of_questions/count($uniqueSubjects));
            $mul = $div*count($uniqueSubjects);

            // Get the remaining test
            $additional_mark_test = $no_of_questions % count($uniqueSubjects);

            $subjects=Subject::whereIn('id',$majorSubjects)->get();
            }
```

In your blade, this will check first if `$additional_mark_test` is empty.

```
@if(!empty($additional_mark_test))
    @foreach($subject->questions->random($additional_mark_test) as $num => $question)
    <form></form>
    @endforeach
    @php $additional_mark_test = 0; @endphp
 @endif
```

Put it in here.

```
 @foreach($subjects as $key => $subject)
              <li class=" {{$key == 0 ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="#tab_{{ $subject->id }}" data-toggle="tab">{{$subject->name}}</a></li>  
              @endforeach
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
              @if(!empty($subjects))
               @foreach($subjects as $key => $subject)
              <div class="tab-pane {{$key == 0 ? 'active' : ''}}" id="tab_{{ $subject->id }}">

                @foreach($subject->questions->random($div) as $num => $question)
                <form></form>
                @endforeach

                 <!--Additional Mark Test(This will be add to first subject)-->
                 @if(!empty($additional_mark_test))
                    @foreach($subject->questions->random($additional_mark_test) as $num => $question)
                    <form></form>
                    @endforeach
                    @php $additional_mark_test = 0; @endphp
                 @endif
```